# Calling functions when the mouse wheel moves

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am a beginner at using javascript and jquery and I don't know a whole lot yet. I am trying to make some code that would call different functions if the mouse wheel moves in certain directions that is compatible with most or all programs. Could some one show me using an example piece of code how to implement this?

This is how I would need it to be set up

```
// JavaScript Document
...
...
...
...   
function wheelMove(){


    // NOTE: I'd like the event of scrolling not to fire 
    // (i.e return false; or something like it)


    // if variables need to be set, they can go here
    //...
    //...
    //...
    if (// some code to detect if the wheel is moving towards the right){

        var sRight = // some code to detect the speed in this direction;
        moveRight(sRight); // calls a function when it moves right;

    }
    if (// some code to detect if the wheel is moving towards the left){

        var sLeft = // some code to detect the speed in this direction;
        moveLeft(sLeft); // calls a function when it moves left;

    }
    if (// some code to detect if the wheel is moving towards the up){

        var sUp = // some code to detect the speed in this direction;
        moveUp(sUp); // calls a function when it moves up;

    }
    if (// some code to detect if the wheel is moving towards the down){

        var sDown = // some code to detect the speed in this direction;
        moveDown(sDown); // calls a function when it moves down;

    }
}
```

Comment: [http://www.sitepoint.com/html5-javascript-mouse-wheel/](http://www.sitepoint.com/html5-javascript-mouse-wheel/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example (and here it is on [jsfiddle.com](http://jsfiddle.net/2gWSh/3/)):

```
$( '#scrollCatcher' ).on( 'mousewheel', function ( event ) {

    // crude check to see events are supported
    if ( typeof event.originalEvent.wheelDeltaX === 'undefined'
        || typeof event.originalEvent.wheelDeltaY === 'undefined' ) {
        console.log( "could not find mouse deltas" );
        return;
    }

    var deltaX = event.originalEvent.wheelDeltaX;
    var deltaY = event.originalEvent.wheelDeltaY;

    var scrolledLeft = deltaX < 0;
    var scrolledRight = deltaX > 0;
    var scrolledUp = deltaY < 0;
    var scrolledDown = deltaY > 0;

    clearDisplay();

    if ( scrolledLeft ) { display( 'scrolled left' ); }
    if ( scrolledRight ) { display( 'scrolled right' ); }
    if ( scrolledUp ) { display( 'scrolled up' ); }
    if ( scrolledDown ) { display( 'scrolled down' ); }
});

function clearDisplay () {
    $( '#scrollCatcher' ).text( '' );
}

function display( message ) {
    $( '#scrollCatcher' ).text( $( '#scrollCatcher' ).text() + message + ' ' );
}
```

To explain `deltaX` and `deltaY` are the distance travelled by the scroll wheel since the last event. Where there is `display` you could replace it with you own code. For example:

```
if ( scrolledLeft ) { moveLeft( deltaX ) }
```

Comment: Isn't there a compatibility issue with firefox and the mousewheel event? I thought firefox doesn't support it... and I really do need to have a scrolling speed...

Comment: There could be. If FF don't support the mousewheel then you won't be able to do it. Worth asking / looking elsewhere on SO.